# NullPointerException on SearchView using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am using `ActionBarSherlock` and Support Library v4. This is in a `SherlockFragmentActivity'.

I am getting a Nullpointer on line 269, referenced below. I have verified SearchView is null, not SearchManager.  Though, `menu` is also null as well, I am not sure if that is normal?  **Important:  It is ONLY null in my Android 4.0 and 4.1 tests.  In 2.3, it works great!**

Here is my `SearchView` Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = 
        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = 
        (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView(); // line 269
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    return true;
}
```

I have this as my menu item now.

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="search"/>
```

**LogCat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.---.---.master.MainFragmentActivity
    .setupSearchView(MainFragmentActivity.java:269)
 at com.---.---.master.MainFragmentActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(
    MainFragmentActivity.java:258)
 at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:45)
 at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(
    ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
 at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(
    ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:479)
 at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat
    .dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:272)
 at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat$1.run(
    ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:984)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(
    ZygoteInit.java:839)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**imports:**

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;

import android.app.SearchManager;
```

Again, I get Null Pointer in ONLY the 4.0 emulator and 4.1 device. App runs great in 2.3.  At one time, pre-ActionBarSherlock, using the SAME code, except importing `SearchView` through the normal way (not Sherlock) it worked great in 4.0.  I am trying to make my app backwards compatible and is broke the newer Android versions, but works great in the older.

**EDIT:**  It was actually Null in 2.3 and Cast Issue in 4.0+ when the menu item had    `android:actionViewClass="android.app.SearchView"`
Then I changed it to    `android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"`
and now FIXED in 2.3 and Null in 4.0+

**UPDATE:  I appeared to fix it with a hack:**

I added a `menu-v11` folder added a duplicate file of menu.xml with one item change only: `android:actionViewClass="android.app.SearchView"`, otherwise it is identical to the other menu.xml file.

In Java, I did this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = 
        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setupNewSearchView(searchItem, searchManager);
    }
    return true;
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupNewSearchView(MenuItem searchItem,
        SearchManager searchManager) {
    android.widget.SearchView searchView = 
        (android.widget.SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
        .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Well, it works, but I'm not putting it as an answer yet because it seems like hack way of doing it.  Open to better ideas?

Comment: Which line you r getting error ?

Comment: Line 269.  I have it marked on in as a comment up above.  I also added update.

Comment: Did you find a better solution? I am having the exact same problem, and don't want to use this workaround, as it defeats the purpose of using the ActionbarSherlock-library to have one codebase for all Android-versions.

Comment: I also got the same problem, and can't fix it during several hours... Does this SearchView from ActionBarSherlock working at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *problem with missing attrs* for v14 (and v11?) in ActionBarSherlock (or ActionBarSherlock + HoloEverywhere + Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar ?).

[Simple solution and details in the issue thread…](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685#issuecomment-14653885)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use two completely different classes, both named SearchView but in different packages.  You cannot simply cast an object from one class into another class.  com.actionbarsherlock.widget.Searchview is different than android.widget.SearchView.  Therefore, `searchView` is null on line 269.

It would be relevant for us to see the imports from the top of your Java file.

Probably, the view referenced by R.id.menu_search is an android.widget.SearchView and your code expects it to be a com.actionbarsherlock.widget.Searchview.

Comment: Update:  I switched my Menu item as seen in new edit on very bottom of question, so I fixed that cast issue, but now I get Nullpointer only in 4.0 emulator; runs fine in 2.3

Comment: Also, wrong casts don't cause NullPointerExceptions but ClassCastExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a theme attribute to your manifest file under the tags of each of the activities that you plan to use an `ActionBar`. You can create your own custom theme or use one of the default offered by `ActionBarSherlock`.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MyActivityWithActionBar"
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
</activity>
```

More information on:

- http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme